# Azure Easy Tables - System.InvalidOperationException: An insert operation on the item is already in the queue

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I upload an item to Azure Easy Tables from Xamarin.Forms app (it was working before) I get:

System.InvalidOperationException: An insert operation on the item is already in the queue.

Is something wrong with Azure or code ?

Thanks for your answers !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely means that it's hanging on to an older piece of data, where the model may have been different to the table definition, or some other formatting issue (common with date types, in my experience).

Without more information, it's very hard to know what the *cause* of the error was, although I'd say the most likely case is the above.

Depending on your setup, you could try...

**1. Deleting the App from the device, clean, build, deploy the project again**

(If you're using `MobileServiceSQLiteStore` Pending operations will be cancelled, and the SQLite DB regenerated using the proper table definition, if these changed at all)

**2. Restart your AppService in Azure Portal**

Sometimes this will work, depending on what has caused the error to take place in the first place. Regardless, if you think you're having troubles with Azure out of the blue, this should be one of the first steps to try.